# Are you matched with 4 player squad as a 3 player squad?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I played my first squad games yesterday and we were a party of 3. I didn't pay attention if there were squads of 4 players against us as we died rather quickly. My question is : Are you exclusively matched with 3 player squad if you're 3 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From my experience:

Solo: Everyone is by themselves (given). 
Duo: You can play alone, or be matched up with a teammate. 
Squad: You *can* play alone, but unless you turn off auto matching, you'll be paired with upwards of 3 others, ideally creating a full squad of 4.

From the [FAQ](https://battlegrounds.gamepedia.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions_(FAQ)) and [Wiki](https://battlegrounds.gamepedia.com/Game_Modes):

> "What type of servers are there? | A: Solo, Duo, SQUADS (team up in
> groups of 2, 3 or 4 players, or if you prefer, you can still play solo
> and take on everyone alone)"
>
> "Each game modes (Solo, Duo, Squad, etc) will be matched independently (For example, Duos cannot be matched with Solo queue)."

**Note:** Auto matching is found next to the queue type you intend to enter under 'PLAY'.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can be matched against teams consisting of 1 - 4 people.

The only modes where you will be matched with even numbers is in Solo.

It's possible to play in Squad/Duo mode on your own if you turn off the auto matching feature.